# Будет ли результат двух запросов одинаковым? И скорость выполнения

Tags: sql

Запрос:

```
        SELECT th.hotel_id, th.tour_id ,
(SELECT name FROM table_hotels WHERE th.hotel_id=hotel_id) AS hotel_name,
(SELECT gcode FROM table_pansions WHERE KEY = th.pansion_gkey) AS pansion,
(SELECT text FROM table_roomcategory WHERE KEY = th.room_category_id) AS room_category, 
(SELECT code FROM table_roomtypelist WHERE KEY = th.room_type_id) AS room_type_code, 
(SELECT name FROM table_roomtypelist WHERE KEY = th.room_type_id) AS room_type_name, 
th.price, th.DATE AS begin_date, t.nday AS duration, t.spo,t.fit,t.holiday,t.leisure,t.spa,t.exc, r.dep_number,r.arr_number,r.dep_time_from,r.arr_time_from,r.dep_time_to,r.arr_time_to,r.port_arr_from,r.port_arr_to,r.port_dep_from,r.port_dep_to,r.dep_class,r.arr_class,r.arr_company,r.dep_company
        FROM table_tourhotels th
        INNER JOIN table_toursrace r ON th.tour_id = r.tour_id
        INNER JOIN table_tours t ON th.tour_id = r.tour_id WHERE hotel_id = 1 LIMIT 10
```

вернет такой же результат как и следующий запрос:

```
SELECT h.name AS hotel_name,pans.gcode AS pansion, rcat.text AS room_category, rtype.code AS room_type_code, rtype.name AS room_type_name,th.hotel_id, th.tour_id , th.price, th.DATE AS begin_date, t.nday AS duration,t.spo,t.fit,t.holiday,t.leisure,t.spa,t.exc,    r.dep_number,r.arr_number,r.dep_time_from,r.arr_time_from,r.dep_time_to,r.arr_time_to,r.port_arr_from,r.port_arr_to,r.port_dep_from,r.port_dep_to,r.dep_class,r.arr_class,r.arr_company,r.dep_company
FROM table_tourhotels th
INNER JOIN table_toursrace r ON th.tour_id = r.tour_id
INNER JOIN table_tours t ON th.tour_id = r.tour_id
LEFT JOIN table_hotels h ON th.hotel_id=h.hotel_id
LEFT JOIN table_pansions pans ON pans.KEY = th.pansion_gkey
LEFT JOIN table_roomcategory rcat ON rcat.KEY = th.room_category_id
LEFT JOIN table_roomtypelist rtype ON rtype.KEY = th.room_type_id
WHERE th.hotel_id = 1
LIMIT 10
```

И как я понимаю второй запрос будет быстрее?

Comment: ну а что вам мешает взять и самому проверить свои запросы? Или вы думаете, что вам тут на глазок прикинут и определят это лучше, чем ваша СУБД? Особенно учитывая размеры запросов и количество сджойненных таблиц

Comment: таблицы огромные и в ручную сверять не реально.
сверил количество возвращаемых результатов, число совпадает... но идентичны они или нет не известно...
вроде с джоинами в 2 раза быстрее справляется

Comment: ну а что же вам мешает замерить время выполнения каждого из них и сравнить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем случае два запроса не эквивалентны. Если у вас все нужные ключи отмечены как PK, то похожи на эквивалентные, хотя я не вчитывался внимательно.

Производительность зависит от вашей СУБД. Посмотрите план запроса (обычно explain). В принципе, многие СУБД переписывают подзапросы в JOIN'ы, если это нужно.

Также если у вас действительно выбираются записи по одному hotel_id, неужели там действительно столько записей, чтобы производительность была важна?

Comment: записей очень много, ну там где вложенные SELECT то там да, PK и меня очень беспокоил вариант будут ли совпадать результаты, спасибо